# Unable to log in to go micro's remote server

Tags: go, kubernetes, authorization, token, go-micro

## Description

Hello, I have been following a [tutorial](https://itnext.io/go-micro-on-kubernetes-getting-started-2959dd6c2d4f) that sets up my own microservice in the cloud with go micro and kubernetes.

The tutorial has a kubernetes cluster as a prerequisite, so I followed another [tutorial](https://jmrobles.medium.com/how-to-create-a-kubernetes-cluster-with-rancher-on-hetzner-3b2f7f0c037a) by the same author to create a kubernetes cluster.

To sum up the tutorials so you may get the big picture:
I first used **Hetzner Cloud** to by some machines on a remote location so I can deploy my **Rancher** server there. **Rancher** is a UI tool for creating and managing a kubernetes cluster.

Therefore, I:

- Bought a machine on Hetzner Cloud
- Deployed my Rancher server there
- Went to a public IP to log into Rancher
- Made a kubernetes cluster with one master and one worker node.
  Everything was successful there, I could download kube's **.config** and manipulate the cluster from the command line.

The next tutorial was on how you deploy **go micro** framework and your own helloworld microservice in the kubernetes cluster.
The tutorial walks you through deploying go micro's services first, and then shows you the deployment for your own microservice.

I managed to do everything and all of my services are up and running. There is just one problem, I can't log into the micro server with username: **admin** and password: **micro**.

## Symptoms

What I can do:

- I can list kubernetes pods with `kubectl get pods -n micro`
- I can log into a particular pod (I logged into `api` like in tutorial) with `kubectl exec -it -n micro {{pod}} -- bash`
- There I see the `micro` exec.
  From there, the tutorial just said log in and execute `./micro services` and it lists all the services, but I am unable to log in. When I try with the default "admin, micro" combination it says `Invalid token provided`.
  I checked the jwt tokens in `MICRO_AUTH_PRIVATE_KEY` and `MICRO_AUTH_PUBLIC_KEY` and they match in every service.

I am able to create another user after which I get `access denied to namespace` error when trying to list the services. I am unable to create rules with that user.

Please help, this has been haunting me for days.